# Андроид интерфейс

Tags: android-sdk, android, html, css, javascript

При написании интерфейса для андроид на языке HTML и CSS возникает такая проблема. Нажимая на ссылку, ссылка выделяеться так же как и в браузере. Вопрос: как сделать так что бы ссылка не выделялась (как это происходит в приложениях написанных на Java). Судя по всему такого рода приложения запускаються через внутренний браузер. Может все таки есть какое то решение ???

Comment: Что значит "выделяется"?

Comment: Можно сказать как в CSS свойство outline. Ну вот например в браузере на Андроид если нажать на ссылку то она выделиться синим фоном и синей обводкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас есть доступ к веб браузерному компоненту то надо там выставить пару флагов:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setClickable(true);
    myWebView.setSelected(false);
    myWebView.setFocusable(false);
    myWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Comment: Ссылка на статью где это все подробно описывается, если кому интересно http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/